# Simplify P(n), where n is a positive integer : $ P(x)=\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{x-1}{(k+x+1)\sqrt{k+1}+(k+2)\sqrt{k+x}}\right). $

Tags: calculus, divergent-series, integers

This is what I have tried, but I don't know what to do next, so I need help

:
$ P(x)=\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{x-1}{(n+x+1)\sqrt{n+1}+(n+2)\sqrt{n+x}}\right). $

$ P(1)=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(1+x+1)\sqrt{1+1}+(1+2)\sqrt{1+x}})$
$=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(2+x)\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt{1+x}})$

$ P(2)=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(2+x+1)\sqrt{2+1}+(2+2)\sqrt{2+x}})$
$=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(3+x)\sqrt{3}+4\sqrt{2+x}})$

$ P(3)=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(3+x+1)\sqrt{3+1}+(3+2)\sqrt{3+x}})$
$=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(4+x)\sqrt{4}+5\sqrt{3+x}})$

$ P(4)=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(4+x+1)\sqrt{4+1}+(4+2)\sqrt{4+x}})$
$=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(5+x)\sqrt{5}+6\sqrt{4+x}})$

$ P(5)=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(5+x+1)\sqrt{5+1}+(5+2)\sqrt{5+x}})$
$=\arctan(\frac{x-1}{(6+x)\sqrt{6}+7\sqrt{5+x}})$

I tried to calculate it for a few numbers to see if there will be any order to conclude something. Only that I conclude is that the series is diverging.

Comment: When evaluating $P(1)$, you should replaces instances of $x$ (and not $k$) with $1$. So you should get $$P(1) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \arctan \left(\frac{1-1}{(k+2)\sqrt{k+1} + (k+2)\sqrt{k+1}}\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \arctan(0) = 0$$

Comment: $ P(1) = \arctan \left(\frac{1-1}{(2(k+2)\sqrt{k+1}}\right) = \arctan(0) = 0 $

$ P(2)= \arctan\left(\frac{2-1}{(k+2+1)\sqrt{k+1}+(k+2)\sqrt{k+2}}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{(k+3)\sqrt{k+1}+(k+2)\sqrt{k+2}}\right) $

$ P(3)=\arctan\left(\frac{3-1}{(k+3+1)\sqrt{k+1}+(k+2)\sqrt{k+3}}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{2}{(k+4)\sqrt{k+1}+(k+2)\sqrt{k+3}}\right) $

$ P(4)=\arctan\left(\frac{4-1}{(k+4+1)\sqrt{k+1}+(k+2)\sqrt{k+4}}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{3}{(k+5)\sqrt{k+1}+(k+2)\sqrt{k+4}}\right) $
... still don't know what to do with that

Comment: For $n\ge2$ we have $P(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^n\text{arccot}\sqrt k.$

Comment: why $\sqrt k$ ?

Comment: There is something to fix about the definition of $P(x)$, since it is defined as a series in the title, while for $x\in \mathbb{N}$ it is defined as a finite sum (in the question body).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume $x$ is an positive integer. Define

$$\begin{cases}
a_n &= \frac{x-1}{(n+x+1)\sqrt{n+1}+(n+2)\sqrt{n+x}}\\
u_n &= \sqrt{n+x}\\
v_n &= \sqrt{n+1}
\end{cases}$$
We have
$$a_n = \frac{u_n^2-v_n^2}{(u_n^2+1)v_n + (v_n^2+1)u_n} = \frac{u_n-v_n}{1 + u_nv_n}
$$
This leads to

$$\tan^{-1}a_n 
= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{u_n-v_n}{1+u_n v_n}\right)
= \left(\tan^{-1}u_n - \tan^{-1}v_n\right) + \pi N
$$
for some integer $N$ to be determined. By throwing in some explicit numbers, it is not hard to see $N = 0$ in this case. As a result, we have

$$\begin{align}
P(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan^{-1} a_n 
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\tan^{-1}\sqrt{n+x} - \tan^{-1}\sqrt{n+1}\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(
\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} - \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+x}}\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{x-1} \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Well done.  A +1